# Files with no attributes, owner, group and inodes

Tags: debian, inode

Yesterday we started having problems with our emails. Investigating this, I found that there some files on our system that show all the attributes including inode, owner, group, permissions, size and date as questions marks when listed by an `ls` command.

When I try to access any of these files to view them, update them, move or delete them, I get an input/output error. Due to the inode also being shown as a question mark rather than a real value, I can't delete them using the inode.

Now I can't even do an `ls` on this system - I get a segmentation fault when I try to run the `ls` command.

Any thoughts on what might be happening and how I can recover from this problem? Is there any further information I might be able to provide that could help towards finding a cause and with luck a solution? The box is running Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Check some logfiles in /var/log, like `messages` or `syslog` for error messages, as well as `less dmesg`. A `fsck` as suggested below cannot be run while the filesystem is mounted. Is that directory on the root fs?

Comment: Is this a local filesystem, or a remotely mounted one as from NFS or Samba?

Answer (score 2):

is your filesystem ok ? Please run fsck to check and fix problems before running any commands to look at the files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the filesystem is definitely not ok. I have found other corrupted files in multiple directories. As well as ls, I also can't run a lot of other commands like cat, less, mdadm, dpkg to name but a few. SO in its present state, I can't actually check anything.

I do know that I can't run fsck while a file system is mounted and have not tried to do so. The system is running software RAID 1 - how do a fsck check in that case? I have only ever used fsck on a non-raid system.

I am guessing that I should be rebooting the system off a live disk first before trying to run fsck and checking the various logfiles.

As you can tell, I am not very experienced. I do have a  drive copy that I created with dd some days ago and I am thinking that restoring from that backup and then recreating & resyncing the raid arrays may, in the longer term, be a quicker option. If I did go down that route, would I better to restore one drive, recreate and resync the raid array or could I restore from the backup drive onto both drives in the raid array (identical 2Tb WD black drives) and